# Shove giving KeyError when assigning value

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror, python-shove

I am using shove to avoid loading a huge dictionary into memory.

```
from shove import Shove

lemmaDict = Shove('file://storage')
with open(str(sys.argv[1])) as lemmaCPT:\
    for line in lemmaCPT:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        lineAr = string.split(line, ' ||| ')
        lineKey = lineAr[0] + ' ||| ' + lineAr[1]
        lineValue = lineAr[2]
        print lineValue
        lemmaDict[lineKey] = lineValue
```

However, I'm getting the following KeyError and Traceback partway through reading `lemmaCPT`. What's going on?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./stemmer.py", line 19, in <module>
    lemmaDict[lineKey] = lineValue
  File "/opt/Python-2.7.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shove/core.py", line 44, in __setitem__
    self.sync()
  File "/opt/Python-2.7.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shove/core.py", line 74, in sync
    self._store.update(self._buffer)
  File "/opt/Python-2.7.6/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py", line 542, in update
    self[key] = other[key]
  File "/opt/Python-2.7.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shove/base.py", line 123, in __setitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: '! ! ! \xd1\x87\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd1\x81\xd1\x8f \xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb5\xd0\xba\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xbc \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbc \xd0\xbb\xd1\x8e\xd0\xb1\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb3\xd0\xbe ||| ! ! ! is pronounced by'
```

Sample input:

```
! ! ! читается троекратным повторением ||| ! ! ! is pronounced by repeating ||| 0.00744887 8.53148e-39 0.00989281 8.53148e-39
! ! ! читается троекратным повторением ||| ! ! ! is pronounced by ||| 0.00744887 8.53148e-39 0.00989281 8.53148e-39
! ! ! читается троекратным повторением ||| ! ! ! is pronounced ||| 0.00744887 8.53148e-39 0.00989281 8.53148e-39
! ! ! читается троекратным повторением ||| ! ! ! is ||| 0.00819374 8.53148e-39 0.00989281 0.0128612
! ! ! читается троекратным повторением ||| ! ! ! ||| 0.000119622 8.53148e-39 0.0098932 0.590703
! ! ! читается троекратным повторением ||| , ! ! ! is pronounced by ||| 0.00819374 8.53148e-39 0.00989281 8.53148e-39
! ! ! читается троекратным повторением ||| , ! ! ! is pronounced ||| 0.00819374 8.53148e-39 0.00989281 8.53148e-39
! ! ! читается троекратным повторением ||| , ! ! ! is ||| 0.00819374 8.53148e-39 0.00989281 0.00154241
! ! ! читается троекратным повторением ||| , ! ! ! ||| 0.0074488 8.53148e-39 0.00989281 0.070842
! ! ! читается троекратным повторением любого ||| ! ! ! is pronounced by repeating ||| 0.00744887 8.53148e-39 0.00989281 8.53148e-39
! ! ! читается троекратным повторением любого ||| ! ! ! is pronounced by ||| 0.00744887 8.53148e-39 0.00989281 8.53148e-39
```

Running `code.py sampleinput` will yield the aforementioned KeyError and Traceback.

Comment: A functional(prototype) code would have more nice...with a sample input.

Comment: I'm gonna dig it first and post if i could find something...

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if this is the actual input then the problem is with length of `LemmaDict` and the `input`...

```
aftnix@dev:~⟫ cat input | wc -l
11
```

My changed code....

```
from shove import Shove
import sys
import string

lemmaDict = Shove('file://storage')
i = 0
with open(str(sys.argv[1])) as lemmaCPT:
    for line in lemmaCPT:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        lineAr = string.split(line, ' ||| ')
        lineKey = lineAr[0] + ' ||| ' + lineAr[1]
        lineValue = lineAr[2]
        print lineValue
        print len(lemmaDict)
        #print len(lemmaCPT)
        i+=1
        print i
        #lemmaDict[lineKey] = lineValue
```

Gives the following output...

```
0.00744887 8.53148e-39 0.00989281 8.53148e-39
9
1
0.00744887 8.53148e-39 0.00989281 8.53148e-39
9
2
0.00744887 8.53148e-39 0.00989281 8.53148e-39
9
3
0.00819374 8.53148e-39 0.00989281 0.0128612
9
4
0.000119622 8.53148e-39 0.0098932 0.590703
9
5
0.00819374 8.53148e-39 0.00989281 8.53148e-39
9
6
0.00819374 8.53148e-39 0.00989281 8.53148e-39
9
7
0.00819374 8.53148e-39 0.00989281 0.00154241
9
8
0.0074488 8.53148e-39 0.00989281 0.070842
9
9
0.00744887 8.53148e-39 0.00989281 8.53148e-39
9
10
0.00744887 8.53148e-39 0.00989281 8.53148e-39
9
```

So you are simply overrunning the `Dict`.

If you delete two lines from the input it will stop throwing exception.

I don't know about shove, but a quick check in shell tells me it always returns a line keyed dict. There has to be a way to grow it...maybe there is a method or something like it...you should dig it's Doc more closely

I just have a feeling you're using `Shove` in a wrong way.

EDIT: It's kind of bizarre...after reviewing the `Shove` code, it turns out it should have synced it's memory content when buffer limit is reached...

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._cache[key] = self._buffer[key] = value
        # when buffer reaches self._limit, write buffer to store
        if len(self._buffer) >= self._sync:
            self.sync()
```

EDIT 2

Well i was totally wrong in my earlier point...But I've got some interesting pointer. One of the problem with is, is that `shove` raised a confusing exception...

The real exception happened because ...

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
   118          # (per Larry Meyn)
   119          try:
   120              with open(self._key_to_file(key), 'wb') as item:
   121                  item.write(self.dumps(value))
   122          except (IOError, OSError):
   123              raise KeyError(key)
```

So the exception actually came from `open` system call. That means it has troubles writing files. I have a new suspicion with the length of the string...

The look of the `storage` folder...

```
 aftnix@dev:~⟫ ls -l storage/                                                                                                                                   
    total 36
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 aftnix aftnix 49 ডিসে   4 01:35 %21+%21+%21+%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F+%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC+%7C%7C%7C+%21+%21+%21

-rw-rw-r-- 1 aftnix aftnix 52 ডিসে   4 01:35 %21+%21+%21+%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F+%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC+%7C%7C%7C+%2C+%21+%21+%21+is+pronounced
```

So `shove` is using key as file name. So it might get very ugly as your string is very large in the last two entries, especially the penultimate entry. So for a test i deleted some characters from the last two lines of the input. And the code ran as expected without any exception.

Linux kernel has a limit of file name length....

```
aftnix@dev:~⟫ cat /usr/include/linux/limits.h 
#ifndef _LINUX_LIMITS_H
#define _LINUX_LIMITS_H

#define NR_OPEN         1024

#define NGROUPS_MAX    65536    /* supplemental group IDs are available */
#define ARG_MAX       131072    /* # bytes of args + environ for exec() */
#define LINK_MAX         127    /* # links a file may have */
#define MAX_CANON        255    /* size of the canonical input queue */
#define MAX_INPUT        255    /* size of the type-ahead buffer */
#define NAME_MAX         255    /* # chars in a file name */
```

So to get around it you have to do something else. You can't put the vanilla parsed key into `Shove`.

Comment: The length of your lemmaDict is 9 in your output because you have already run it once and Shove is accessing your dictionary from last time (which is on disk in a directory called storage). Delete the directory and run it again.

Comment: Yeah I got it wrong in the first time. Actually shove did a poor job by throwing a completely wrong exception which made me confused. See Edit 2.